# Sass mutual properties for items

Tags: sass

I'm creating a grid system with Sass. I have created classes from .col1 to .col8. Now I want to dynamically make a mutual selector (.col1, .col2, ..., .col8) for all these classes. How can I do this?

```
$siteWidth: 80em
$columnCount: 8
$columnWidth: $siteWidth / $columnCount

@for $i from 1 through $columnCount
  .col#{$i}
    width: $columnWidth * $i
```

Comment: Did you try that code?  Did you get an error (what was the error)?  Incorrect output?

Comment: @cimmanon, yeah the code didn't even compile at first, but after some massaging and using a `placeholder` the OP can get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `placeholder`, this `Sass`:

```
$siteWidth: 80em;
$columnCount: 8;
$columnWidth: $siteWidth / $columnCount;

%col {
  height: 10px;
}

.col1 {
  @extend %col;
}

@for $i from 1 through $columnCount {
  .col#{$i} {
    @extend %col;
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through $columnCount {
  .col#{$i} {
    width: $columnWidth * $i;
  }
}
```

will generate this `CSS`:

```
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5, .col6, .col7, .col8 {
  height: 10px; }

.col1 {
  width: 10em; }

.col2 {
  width: 20em; }

.col3 {
  width: 30em; }

.col4 {
  width: 40em; }

.col5 {
  width: 50em; }

.col6 {
  width: 60em; }

.col7 {
  width: 70em; }

.col8 {
  width: 80em; }
```

Now, you may not want to set the `height` property, but you get the idea.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!